# Show $L^2$ is not closed in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $X \subset L^1_{([0,1])}$ is the subspace consisting of all square-integrable functions. I have to show that $X$ is not a closed subset of $L^1_{([0,1])}$. How do I go about doing this? What exactly do I need to prove?

Comment: You need to find a sequence of square-integrable functions whose limit in the $L^1$ norm is not square integrable. A useful function to think about here is $x^{-1/2}$.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer

Comment: As Jochen's answer shows, this is not true as stated.  Did you mean $X$ to be *the* subspace consisting of *all* square-integrable functions, or at least that $X$ be infinite-dimensional?

Comment: Fixed, sorry haha.

Comment: @Nate: $X$ infinite-dimensional would not be good enough: If $Y_n$ is a sequence of independent Gaussians, all $L^p$-norms on their closed linear span  $X$ in $L^2$ are constant multiples of the $L^2$-norm, so $X$ is a closed subspace of all $L^p$-spaces for $1 \leq p \lt \infty$.

Comment: I adjusted the title to be less confusing.

Answer (score 1):

There are closed subspaces of $L^1[0,1]$ consisting of square-integrable functions
(e.g. every finite-dimensional subspace is closed). However, the closed graph theorem shows that on every $L^1$-closed subspace of $L^2$ the two norms $\|\cdot\|_1$
and $\|\cdot\|_2$ are eqivalent. This may help in concrete situations.